# Set width to 110

Tags: jquery

In the example, Why the width isn't 110. I know it's because of border. But what is the cross-browser way to set width to 110.

http://jsfiddle.net/RS5wf/

Comment: you know the difference between `.width()` and `.outerWidth()`, don't you? and you know the calculation of `width` (and that `border` is included) ...

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair According to the documentation, `.width()` does not include the border. It returns the css width as a numeric value, border adds to that value but does not change what `.css('width')` returns.

Comment: @KevinB correct - it does *not* include the border. so if we have the browser-style of `border-width: 2px;` everything gets clear now, doesn't it? (see my adapted `border-width`-example @ http://jsfiddle.net/RS5wf/4/)

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair - Wow, that seems very inconsistent. The getter subtracts the border width from the output, while the setter ignores whether or not there is a border-width. unless I'm misinterpreting this.

Comment: @KevinB ... yes and no ... according to the docu (http://api.jquery.com/width/) `Note that .width() will always return the content width, regardless of the value of the CSS box-sizing property.` (for getting) and `Note that .width("value") sets the width of the box in accordance with the CSS box-sizing property. Changing this property to border-box will cause this function to change the outerWidth of the box instead of the content width.` (for setting) ... it's all documented :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try getting the width with [outerWidth](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/), which takes into account padding and border.

http://jsfiddle.net/RS5wf/2/

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a lesser known property called `box-sizing`.

Box sizing determines what box model is used to render an object.

content-box is the default for most elements however form elements tend to default to border-box which can be a little frustrating when styling form elements.

Here is a great link on [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Box-sizing)

Answer (score 0):

The width can be read either using .width(), which returns the inner width (removing padding and border pixels), or .outerWidth(), which returns the total width.

The width can only be set using .width(size), not with .outerWidth(size).